# Why do garbage disposal companies suggest using cold water with their products?

Tags: plumbing, garbage-disposal

Why do garbage disposal companies suggest using cold water with their products?

Comment: engine cooling would be my guess

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that food waste disposers will include more grease going down the drain due to the variety of items being disposed, I've been told that cold water helps coagulate grease into chunks that wash down the drain. Somehow this helps reduce grease buildup in the trap. I would suspect that cold+liquid grease at the disposal gets broken up without gumming up the works, but warm liquid grease will coagulate in the cutters/trap as it cools and settles.

According to this [GE Disposal User Guide (PDF)](http://products.geappliances.com/MarketingObjectRetrieval/Dispatcher?RequestType=PDF&Name=49-5903-2.pdf)

> Do not use hot water while running the disposer. Cold water will keep food waste and fats solid so they can be flushed down the drain.

Answer (score 7):

The manual for the garbage disposal I just installed says to use cold water because hot water could cause the motor to overheat.

Comment: Any chance you could link to an online copy of the manual, and quote the exact text here?

Comment: Maybe. The manual is in the trash now so I'll have stick my head in the cabinet when I get home.